# PHP long string without newline

Tags: php, string, break

I have a long string in php which does not contain new lines ('\n').

My coding convention does not allow lines longer than 100 characters.

Is there a way to split my long string into multiple lines without using the . operator which is less efficient - I don't need to concat 2 strings as they can be given as a
single string.

Thanks!

Y

Answer (score 3):

That's easy:

```
$str  = 'long text long text long text long text long text';
$str .= 'long text';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could strip newline characters from the string:

```
  $myStr = "
    here is my string
    and it is spread across multiple lines
  ";
  $myStr = str_replace("\n", "", $myStr);
```

You should still use the concatenation operator (.) for such things. The performance penalty here is negligible if you're using opcode caching (APC) and this would really not be anything noticeable when taking DB access and additional logic (including loops) into the run time equation.

**Update:**

Give the page below a read. The conclusion above is not readily available in the text, but a careful examination should show it is valid.

http://blog.golemon.com/2006/06/how-long-is-piece-of-string.html

Comment: How does opcode caching affect the speed of string concatenation?

Comment: The parser would treat strings with no dynamic elements to be one long string, dropping the concatenation operators. I've dug into this subject a while ago. Will update this answer with the related article once I manage to find it again.

Comment: It get's me `"    here is my string    and it is spread across multiple lines  "`. Doesn't look like any sensible result

Answer (score 0):

This is the right code, that solved all issues:

```
$myStr = "
    here is my string
    and it is spread across multiple lines
  ";
  $myStr = str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $myStr);
```

It is based on Lior Cohen's answer, but it also strips carriage returns "\r".

Comment: It get's me `"    here is my string    and it is spread across multiple lines  "`. Doesn't look like any sensible result

Answer (score -1):

With the [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax (or [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc), depending on your needs, check the documentation link):

```
$multiline = <<<EOT
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
$singleline = str_replace("\n","",$multiline);
```

But this sucks... sorry :-)

Comment: The problem with heredoc is that it will include the newline characters in the string, which would then have to be stripped out to get the "string which does not contain newlines" that the question specified.

Comment: Yes, however that would also have a performance hit just as using concatenation would.

Comment: But I think the hit would be slower... One would have to measure.